# Creating overflow on only a few columns in table

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hey i'm trying to create a table within a set frame, and it has waaaay to many columns. The last column though holds some links that i want always visible, the same for the first two columns (id,title). I would like the in between column to be horizontally scrollable.

So basically i have this:

```
    <table>
     <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Test Col 1</th>
        <th>Test Col 2</th>
        <th>Test Col 3</th>
        <th>Test Col 4</th>
        <th>Test Col 5</th>
        <th>Test Col 6</th>
        <th>LINKS</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Test Title</td>
        <td>Col 1</td>
        <td>Col 2</td>
        <td>Col 3</td>
        <td>Col 4</td>
        <td>Col 5</td>
        <td>Col 6</td>
        <td>LINK 1  | LINK 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Test Title</td>
        <td>Col 1</td>
        <td>Col 2</td>
        <td>Col 3</td>
        <td>Col 4</td>
        <td>Col 5</td>
        <td>Col 6</td>
        <td>LINK 1  | LINK 2</td>
     </tr>
     </table>
```

So the table is to wide for my view, and i would always like to display columns 1,2 and the last from my table but make the rest in between fill up my remaining space and then scroll (horizontally) in between those. Where would i go for this???

Comment: use classes for the 2 columns so you can target them as columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you place the first two columns in their own table, and then the last column in it's own table?  You can then set a fixed width for the interior table and set it's overflow to scroll.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uZfbp/5/).

HTML:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Title</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Test Title</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Test Title</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="middle">
<table border="1" width="100%">     
    <tr>
        <th>Test Col 1</th>
        <th>Test Col 2</th>
        <th>Test Col 3</th>
        <th>Test Col 4</th>
        <th>Test Col 5</th>
        <th>Test Col 6</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Col 1</td>
        <td>Col 2</td>
        <td>Col 3</td>
        <td>Col 4</td>
        <td>Col 5</td>
        <td>Col 6</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Col 1</td>
        <td>Col 2</td>
        <td>Col 3</td>
        <td>Col 4</td>
        <td>Col 5</td>
        <td>Col 6</td>
     </tr>
     </table>
</div>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>LINKS</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>LINK 1  | LINK 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>LINK 1  | LINK 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table { float:left; table-layout:fixed; }
.middle {  float:left; width:350px; overflow:auto;}
.middle table td, .middle table th { width:100px; background:red; }
```

Comment: Not 100% what i was hoping for, but it will work. Thanks!!
I actually don't like the multiple tables, but it's something i didn't think off.

Comment: Yeah, it isn't ideal, but I'm not sure there is another solution. If you find something more elegant, please share.

Comment: I will, working on it right now.

This solution gives me problems with sorting in cakePHP

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very simplified jquery approach:

http://jsfiddle.net/pmDpa/

HTML

```
<table>
     <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Test Col 1</th>
        <th>Test Col 2</th>
        <th>Test Col 3</th>
        <th>Test Col 4</th>
        <th>Test Col 5</th>
        <th>Test Col 6</th>
        <th>LINKS</th>
     </tr>
</table>
```

JQUERY

```
$('th:nth-child(3)').addClass('no-show');
$('th:nth-child(4)').addClass('no-show');
$('th:nth-child(5)').addClass('no-show');
$('th:nth-child(6)').addClass('no-show');
$('th:nth-child(7)').addClass('no-show');
$('th:nth-child(8)').addClass('no-show');
```

CSS

```
.no-show { display:none; }
```